# Customer Community Self-Registration

Tags: community, registration

For the self-registration page in our customer community, we'd like to be able to do the following:

1. With the provided First Name and Last Name, match that with an existing Contact in Salesforce. If not in Salesforce, create a new contact (which I think Salesforce does this portion anyway).
2. Have a zip code field for the customer to enter their zip code.
3. Have another field called "Account Name" that displays accounts based on the zip code provided above.

Does anyone know if this is possible? I tried via conventional methods but it doesn't look like the User object can link to the Account object.

Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We actually had to use Apex to then create a custom component for self-registration to meet our needs above.

Answer (score 2):

The self-registration creates a `User` object and if the `Contact` doesn't already exist creates that as well. The relationships are:

- a `User.ContactId` field that links the `User` to the `Contact`
- a `Contact.AccountId` field that links the `Contact` to the `Account`

When you have figured out which `Account`, you pass its Id into the [Site. createExternalUser](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_sites.htm#apex_System_Site_createExternalUser).

For the case where the `Contact` does not exist, I think this will work with the `Contact` tied to the right `Account`. I suspect if the `Contact` already exists, it won't be moved so you would have to do that yourself; not sure if you will be able to though.

Also in my experience, the matching to an existing `Contact` is done via a `User.Email` to `Contact.Email` field match when the `Site. createExternalUser` call is made so consider that in the logic too.